# Vários GROUP BY MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to mount the sql that does the following query, in the `TYPE` field there are both type CUT and RELIANCE, but I need each of them to come in a column, but only I can now show it in each one in a line is possible to do so?

```
SELECT id_user, date_conclusion, type, COUNT (*) 
FROM the 
WHERE id_user = 8 and date_conclusion LIKE '2017-12%'
GROUP by date_conclusion, type
```

[image]

Comment: Post sample data, desired output, and current actual output.

Comment: @underscore_d ready updated, I added a picture of the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that only these two types exist. You do not need the extra type column then:

```
SELECT 
  id_user, 
  date_conclusion, 
  SUM(type = 'CORTE') AS 'CORTE', 
  SUM(type = 'RELIGACAO') AS 'RELIGACAO'
FROM 
  the 
WHERE 
  id_user = 8 AND 
  date_conclusion LIKE '2017-12%'
GROUP BY
  date_conclusion
```